# Maths, RNS residue number system, 2^n + 3 modulo way to compute. c++, bitset

Tags: c++, math, design-patterns, modulo, bitset

I am looking for the way of computing modulo 2^n +3 from bigger number.
The problem is that i don't know how to fast compute it and there is nothing on web.

I got some help for modulo of 2^n -3 and it works by that way:

Separate bits by the max length of modulo then for each of gained parts do. Multiply them by 3^m where m = number of part (for example part_1 * 3^0,part_2 * 3^1 , part_3 * 3^2). You can use the quick metod for getting the multiplied bits by using this. When you have 3^2 = 9 = 8+1 = 2^3 +1. Now you can just add the moved by 3 to the left bits of used part  and adding to it not moved same part. That way i could get the results for each part then add them and do it again on acquired number till i have number lower than my modulo.

Example:
We have bits 1100101101 (813), this is our number, now we use modulo 2^n-3 that is for us (2^4)-3 it is basically 13. Our modulo is 1101 in binary. Now we do 1100101101 mod 1101. We split our number to 4 digits parts. 1101 is first from right and it is 1101 * 1, next is 0010 and it is 0010 * 3 where 3 is (2+1) so we can use like 0010 -> 0100 by moving the bits and adding to it 0010 for that 1 left, next is 11 so it is 11 * 3^2 (2^3 +1) so we have 3 position move and we get 11000 + 11= adding the bits we have 3 numbers 1101 + 0110 + 11011 = 101110. Now we repeat the process 1110 + 110 = 101110. Again we repeat 1110 + 110 = 10100, repeat and we have 0100 + 11 = 111. So we get 7 at the end 813 mod 13 = 7. Correct.

So there is any pattern like that for modulo 2^n+3 ??

Comment: What is the maximum value for `n`?

Comment: Is the value `2^n` a constant?

Comment: 2^n is constant, in my example n = 32.

Comment: I don't understand your third paragraph at all.  Could you give a more complete example?

Comment: I've give the use example, how it works. If you know how i can bite the 2^3 + 3 i would appriciate help :). + as you can see we didnt even use our 13 to compute it, we just look at the bits number of modulo and count it  by moving some bits, adding some etc.